# How can I use registerJS() to produce the following script tag?

Tags: yii2

I have the following JS code that I am placing on the top of my view file. I need to use `registerJS()` because right now Yii2 loads jQuery after my script. Note that all questions on `registerJS()` load an external file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#filter').hide();
    $('a.view_more1').live("click", function(e) {
        var views = "";
        $(".views input:checked").each(function() {
            views += this.value+',';
        });
        offset = document.getElementById('offset').value;
        var record = document.getElementById('record').value;
        var record1 = document.getElementById('record1').value;
        var url = '<?php //echo URL; ?>' + 'products/all_products_1?offset=' + offset + '&record=' + record+'&views='+views+'&main='+'<?php echo $cat; ?>'+'&sub='+'<?php echo $sub_cat; ?>'+'&sec='+'<?php echo $sec_cat; ?>'+'&third='+'<?php echo $third_cat; ?>'+'&price1='+price_text;
        $.post(url, function(check) {
            if (check) {
                $('#product').append(check);
                $('#loading').show();
                $('.wloader_img').hide();
                offset = parseInt(offset) + 12;
                $("#offset").val(offset);
                if (offset >= record1) {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }} });  }); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to register it in your view you can use `$this->registerJS('your js code here')`. To make this approach more readable consider use of [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc):

```
$js =<<<JS
    $('#filter').hide();
    $('a.view_more1').live("click", function(e) {
        var views = "";
        $(".views input:checked").each(function() {
            views += this.value+',';
        });
        offset = document.getElementById('offset').value;
        var record = document.getElementById('record').value;
        var record1 = document.getElementById('record1').value;
        var url = '$URL' + 'products/all_products_1?offset=' + offset + '&record=' + record+'&views='+views+'&main='+'$cat'+'&sub='+'$sub_cat'+'&sec='+'$sec_cat'+'&third='+'$third_cat'+'&price1='+price_text;
        $.post(url, function(check) {
            if (check) {
                $('#product').append(check);
                $('#loading').show();
                $('.wloader_img').hide();
                offset = parseInt(offset) + 12;
                $("#offset").val(offset);
                if (offset >= record1) {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
JS;
```

and then `$this->registerJS($js)`. Note that `$(document).ready()` not needed because by default `registerJS()` will place your code into `$(document).ready()` function internally.

As another option you can create an asset bundle class and register it in your view:

```
class MyAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $js = [
        'js/myscript.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
    ];
}
```

and then in your view: `MyAsset::register($this);`, dont forget to specify namespace of the asset class.

Comment: Can you please give an example of the first option using my code. I tried this already by I get error of `unexpected $` at ` $('#color_filter').hide();` I was also having a problem creating the url to give to post function.

Comment: You might want to use the "non-parsing" variant of the heredoc then: `$js = <<<'JS' ` instead, its seeing things as variables.

Comment: @Blizz that solved my error but I still cannot make post using url

Comment: @Sunday updated the answer with your code. note `$URL` parameter replace it with your desired url. also note that there is no `<?php echo` inside *heredoc*

Comment: `unexpected $` - you get this error in browser console ?